# How to know how many miliseconds a KEY pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just using hotkeys to create a move in a game.I wanted to add hold keys for **X** time.I wanted to know there is way to know how many miliseconds a key pressed?

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about? Console? Winforms? WPF? Unity? ...?

Comment: @itsme86 We r talking about  winforms

Comment: In the KeyDown event, capture the time. In the KeyUp event, capture the time again, compare the results.

Comment: There are overridable methods `OnKeyUp` and `OnKeyDown`. Use them. Ignore repeating `OnKeyUp`.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a couple of class members to hold which key was pressed and the time.

```
private KeyChar _pressedKey;
private Stopwatch _keyPressStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```

Then write your `KeyDown` event handler to put values in those variables:

```
private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _keyPressStopwatch.Restart();
    _pressedKey = e.KeyChar;
}
```

Now write a `KeyUp` event handler to do the rest of the work:

```
private void KeyReleased(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar != _pressedKey)  // We only care about the last key pressed.
        return;

    _keyPressStopwatch.Stop();
    double milliseconds = _keyPressStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    // milliseconds is now how long the key was pressed. Do something with it.
}
```

Don't forget to subscribe to the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events for whatever control is associated with this.

**EDIT**

An excellent point about timing precision was raised in the comments, so I switched the code from using `DateTime.UtcNow` to using a `Stopwatch`.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow does not get updated frequently enough to time keystrokes with sufficient precision, Stopwatch is required.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct. Expanding upon that; Microsoft says `The resolution of this property depends on the system timer, which depends on the underlying operating system. It tends to be between 0.5 and 15 milliseconds`.

Comment: @HansPassant You bring up a great point. I've updated my answer to use a `Stopwatch` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Test : Form
{
   private int _iteration = 0;
    private Stopwatch _sw;
    private int _pressedKey;

    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == _pressedKey) return;
        _iteration++;
        _sw = new Stopwatch();
        _sw.Start();
        _pressedKey = e.KeyValue;
    }

    private void Test_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _pressedKey = -1;
        label1.Text = $"Iteration:{_iteration}. Elapsed: {_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
    }
}
```